# How do I troubleshoot the "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated" error in GridDB?

Tags: griddb

Can you assist me in determining the issue with my code?

```
import griddb_python as gdb

# Connect to the GridDB server
factory = gdb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
store = factory.get_store(host='localhost', port=31999)

# Insert a new customer into the "Customers" table
store.put(container_name='Customers', rows=[(1, 'John Smith', 
'john.smith@example.com', '555-555-5555'),
(2, 'Jane Doe', 'jane.doe@example.com', '555-555-5556')])

ORA-00001: unique constraint (sales.PK_Customers) violated
```